# Linq group by condition

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I provide the simple list as below :

```
var records = new List<BookRecord> {
            new() {
                Author = "Peter",
                BookName = "Book A"
            },
            new() {
                Author = "",
                BookName = "Book B"
            },
            new() {
                Author = "Peter",
                BookName = "Book C"
            },
            new() {
                Author = "James",
                BookName = ""
            },
            new() {
                Author = "",
                BookName = "Book D"
            },
            new() {
                Author = "James",
                BookName = ""
            },
            new() {
                Author = "",
                BookName = "Peter"
            }
        };
```

I want to group only author is not empty (or other condition) , and the remain need to keep into result , so my expected result will be :

```
[
  {"Author":"Peter","BookName":"Book A"},
  {"Author":"","BookName":"Book B"},
  {"Author":"James","BookName":""},
  {"Author":"","BookName":"Book D"},
  {"Author":"","BookName":"Peter"}
]
```

and need to in ordering (that mean "james" should be row 3 and the last one must be `{"Author":"","BookName":"Peter"}`

can I know how to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: records.Where(x => x.Author != "").GroupBy(x => .......

Comment: @jdweng: we should *preserve* records with *empty* `Author` not get rid of them with `.Where(x => x.Author != "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you want

1. If `Author` is **set** (not an empty string) return his/her *first* book only.
2. If `Author` is **not set** just return the record.

If it's your case, you can either `GroupBy` followed by `Select` + `First`:

```
int index = 0;

var result = source
  .GroupBy(item => (item.Author, string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Author) ? ++index : 0))
  .Select(group => group.First())
  .ToList(); // if you want it as a list
```

The trick is to make all groups with empty `Author` being *unique* which we do with a help of `index`.

If we don't want to use *side effects* with `index` we can exploit the same idea but with longer query:

```
var result = source
  .Select((value, index) => (value, index))
  .GroupBy(pair => (pair.value.Author, string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.value.Author) 
                      ? pair.value.index 
                      : 0),
           pair => pair.value)
  .Select(group => group.First())
  .ToList(); // if you want it as a list
```

Comment: Thank you , that's what I want , because. I need to keep index

Comment: I have one more question, if I want to groupby add more column, how to do it ?

Comment: @Carrie Kaski: just add it to the *tuple*: `item => (item.Author, item.AnotherColumn, string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Author) ? ++index : 0)` and you'll get grouping by *combination* of `Author` and `AnotherColumn`

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use this :)

```
var filteredRecords = records
            .Where(x => x.Author != "") //condition
            .OrderBy(x=> x.Author)  // Order by 
            .ToList();
```

Result will be

```
Author :James - BookName: 
Author :James - BookName: 
Author :Peter - BookName: Book A
Author :Peter - BookName: Book C
```

Example code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/cxYVTY

Comment: Please note, that we should *preserve* records with *empty* author, e.g. `{"Author":"","BookName":"Book D"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = records.GroupBy(
         g=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Author)? 
             $"{g.Author}-{g.BookName}"
             :g.Author)
.Select(s=>s.First());
```

Comment: Nice idea, but there's *possible counter example*: if we have *several* records with no author and the *same* book name we should return them *all*; in your case these records will be grouped and only one be returned